# MYSQL NTILE function start with highest percentile

Tags: mysql

I'm using the MYSQL NTILE function and for the most part it is doing what I need it to, however there is one case in which I need different behaviour and I can't figure out how to do it. The case is when I have more buckets than I do records.

So lets say my data in a table called `data` looks like this

```
ID    val
1     15
2     20
3     10
```

My issue is when I have more buckets than I do records, so lets say I run

```
select *, NTILE(4) over (order by val) from data
```

This will result in

```
ID    val    NTILE
3     10     1
1     15     2
2     20     3
```

I'm having some trouble wording my question which is probably why I am struggling to find solutions on Google, but basically **my question is this**: Is there any way that when I have more buckets than records (in this example 4 buckets but only 3 records) that I can treat the highest value as the highest percentile and work backwards rather than what it is currently doing which is treating the lowest value as the lowest percentile? Essentially resulting in this:

```
ID    val    NTILE
2     20     4
1     15     3
3     10     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to reverse the ordering in the `NTILE()` and numerically flip the result like so:

```sql
select *, 5-NTILE(4) over (order by val desc) from data
```

I would expect the following to happen (I have not run this though!):

```
ID    val    NITLE
2     20     4
1     15     3
3     10     2
```